# Is 3DS Max the sofware used to design all game contents?

Tags: 3d, 3dsmax

Please tell me what is the software which persons or companies use it to design the graphics of games (2D and/or 3D), is it 3DS Max? Is there any other software or any more simple software?

Comment: It's like asking if all novels are written in Windows Notepad... ;p

Answer (score 2):

There's quite a huge list of softwares that can be used. The ones I'm listing here are the most popular ones, but you could do all your assets using paint and notepad

#### 3D Models

- 3DS Max is often used for low poly models.
- ZBrush is often used for high poly, and sculpting
- Photoshop/Any other image manipulation tool is used for texturing

#### 2D Assets

- Photoshop/Fireworks/Any image manipulation tool.

There is also XSI for animation and modeling, but it is less used.

Comment: Don't forget Maya as an alternative for 3DS Max, it's commonly used by game studios. (And of course there is the free alternative Blender, but I don't know much that is used by game companies)

Comment: There's also Lightwave, which is mostly used for TV and Film, but its low cost of entry and separation of modeller from animation/cinematics has allowed it to pick up a sizeable market amongst the indie developers in the last couple of years. In case you can't tell, it's also my personal favourite.

Comment: @RoyT.Maya is more commonly used for huge scenes, not independent models though.

Comment: @pikzen - Not really. They are both used large and small, it just depends on the company and the particular modeller.

Comment: Animators tend to prefer Maya, architecture modelers tend to prefer Max. Both at capable of doing whatever is needed for game development.

Also most of the time these days, individual elements are developed in the off the shelf software packages. Then they are assembled in a custom tool or map editor.

Answer (score 2):

No, Max is not used to design *all* game content. *Some* studios may use it to design *some* content, but there are many options for building content.

Some studios use Max, some use Maya, some use proprietary tools. Max and Maya are both 3D modelling programs, so some studios that do primarily 2D artwork probably use something like Photoshop (or again, something custom-written).